# Linear algebra equations by linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We got the linear transformation:
$$T_a:\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}x_1-2x_2-x_3\\2x_1-3x_2-x_3\\x_1-x_2+ax_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-1\\2&-3&-1\\1&-1&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$$

And I have found the inverse:
$$A_a^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
 -3-\frac{1}{a}& 2+\frac{1}{a} &-\frac{1}{a}\\
-2-\frac{1}{a} &1+\frac{1}{a} &-\frac{1}{a} \\
\frac{1}{a}&-\frac{1}{a}&\frac{1}{a}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I have to find x so $T_a(x)=T^{-1}_a(x)$. How can I solve this? If I got $Ax=x$ I could solve it by using $x(A-I)=0$ but now $A^{-1}$ is multiplied on right side. So what can I solve to solve this equations system?

Comment: "Now I have to find $x$" - then take $x=0$. Both are linear maps, so $T_a(0)=T_a^{-1}(0)=0$. In general we have $T_a^2(x)=x$. So $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ of $T_a^2$.

Comment: Yeah I see that the 0 vector works, but that seems to be too easy. Is that that the only solution. We have not yet learned about eigenvectors and eigenvalues in the course, so I don't think I can use it

Comment: Then you have to do the computation, i.e., so solve $Ax=x$ for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t$.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the $a$ subscript, you want to find $x$ with
$$
T(x) = T^{-1}(x),
$$
where
$$
T(x) = Ax,
$$
right? So this can be rewritten as finding $x$ with
$$
Ax = A^{-1} x.
$$
If you multiply both sides by $A$, this becomes
$$
A^2 x = x.
$$
Letting $B = A^2$, you now have to find $x$ with
$$
Bx = x,
$$
which is a kind of problem you say that you know how to do...so...go for it!